# Input not being added to array (beginner) JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

When text is written into the input box and then the button is clicked, I want the text (value) to be added to the array I have created for it (the array is called 'subject'). The text (value) from the input box is not being added... why?

```js
var subject = [];
function addSubjects() {
  namesInputted = document.getElementById('namesInputter').value;
  subject.push(namesInputted);
  console.log(subject);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Prueva tu Suerte</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="namesInputter" value="">
    <button onclick="addSubjects()">Add Player</button>
  </form>
  <span id='S'></span>
  <span id='V'></span>
  <span id='O'></span>
  <span id='P'></span>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="function.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `<button onclick="addSubjects()" type="button">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, You code is working. The input value is appending to the `array`. **But the Issue is**, You are using `form`. So when you click the button, It will submit the form right after add the value to `array`. So page will refresh and the `array` will become empty.

Just remove `form` tag, if you don't want to submit data.

```js
var subject = [];
function addSubjects() {
  namesInputted = document.getElementById('namesInputter').value;
  subject.push(namesInputted);
  console.log(subject);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Prueva tu Suerte</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="namesInputter" value="">
  <button onclick="addSubjects()">Add Player</button>
  <span id='S'></span>
  <span id='V'></span>
  <span id='O'></span>
  <span id='P'></span>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="function.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use form submit with jQuery, you can use like this:

Html

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="namesInputter" value="">
  <button type="submit">Add Player</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
var subject = [];
function addSubjects(e) {
}

$("form").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  namesInputted = document.getElementById('namesInputter').value;
  subject.push(namesInputted);
  console.log(subject);
});
```